# Marshall MAP to JSON

Tags: json, go

I'm in the process of getting started with moving from Python to GoLang and I'm trying to get my head around datatype. I need to marshall a map to the following JSON but I'm not quite sure how my map should be constructed.

This is what I've tried but its not working for me.

```
data := map[string]string{"Offset": "0", "Properties": map[string]string{"key": "Type", "value": "User"}, "Category": "all", "Locations": map[string]string{}, "Accounts": "100" }
data_json, _ := json.Marshal(data)
fmt.Println(string(data_json))
```

***Desired Result:***

```
{
"Locations": [],
"Dates": [],
"Properties": [
  {
    "key": "Type",
    "value": "User"
  }
 ],
 "Category": "all",
 "Accounts": [],
 "Offset": 0,
 "Limit": 100
}
```

Comment: Is the issue that its not being marshalled as you expect, or its just not working? A simple way to find out why its not working would be to not ignore the error passed back and log it if its not nil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that you're claiming to write a map of strings to strings (key is a string AND value is a string). But you have the key/value pair: `"Properties": map[string]string{"key": "Type", "value": "User"}`, and that value is not a string, its another map. If you define the data as a map of strings to interfaces, it should work. That would look more like this:

```
data := map[string]interface{}{"Offset": "0", "Properties": map[string]string{"key": "Type", "value": "User"}, "Category": "all", "Locations": map[string]string{}, "Accounts": "100" }
```

Here is a working example: 
http://play.golang.org/p/HjHH463J_r

If you're unsure what interfaces are and why they work, the documentation explains it pretty well.

Comment: And just have in mind that json.Marshal alphabetically arranges the "keys", so in the json data it will first go: "Accounts", then "Category" etc.

Comment: Arr I see. This is really helpful thank you. I notice when I run this the key/values for locations, dates, properties and accounts are wrapped in curly brackets and not square brackets.

Comment: The package will marshal maps to curly brackets and slices to square brackets. Here's that same example with the `Locations` switched to a slice of strings: http://play.golang.org/p/X5o2FRUYx6

Comment: Thanks again - looks like I need to do some reading here. This stuff is a fair bit different compared to the way I did things using Python.

Comment: Hmm - Just tried changing the properties to use a slice but I get an "array index must be non-negative integer constant" http://play.golang.org/p/zahLg3KjvY

Comment: `Properties` is a map. Map allows key/value pairs. Slice requires that you include only a list of values of the type that the slice is defined to accept.

Comment: OK I think I that, but how can I get a slice within the map?

Comment: It would have to be a map that accepts slices, so either
`map[string][]string` or `map[string]interface{}`. I think we're getting beyond the range of this question, so if you have any more confusion, please ask about it in a new question

Comment: I moved this to a new question but I think the context got slightly lost. Is what I'm trying to achieve here even possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?